# Synapse launcher doesn't open files from a second partition

Tags: synapse

Synapse launcher is able to show various files (text, media) on one of my ntfs partitions (that I use in parallel from Windows too), but cannot open those  files, while it can open files from my Linux partition, my home files.

In my case is Synapse 0.2.99 in Mint 19.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug described [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/synapse-project/+bug/1572121).

It involves the fact described [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/synapse-project/+bug/1572121/comments/10).

> Synapse broke how things work with files with executable permission.
> If it has executable permission it tries to execute file instead of
> opening file with relevant app.

So, as said at that link, a solution would be to remove the executable permission for all such files or, as said [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/synapse-project/+bug/1572121/comments/14), add `noexec` in the options column of `/etc/fstab` for that partition.

I prefer to use "Disks" (`gnome-disk-utility`, can be run as `gnome-disks`) in order to automatically mount that partition.

So, in "Disks", selecting that partition and its mount options, (where I had already) unchecked the defaults and checked to mount at startup (setting a mount point): the solution was to add `noexec` at the list of options for that partition.

[image]

***After reboot*** Synapse was able to open all files in their relevant applications.